# cannot access http, only https

Tags: iis

on my IIS server, I create a web application and add two bindings:

```
1. http 80 binding for www.mydomain.com
2. https 443 binding for www.mydomain.com
```

I can only access , when I access http://www.mydomain.com, I got this problem:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came up in my mind is your ISP. Some ISPs block port 80 for incoming traffic couse they don't want their customers to have their own webite hosts at home.

Comment: but there is another website running on IIS with http, and it is running fine?